# Video playing in background in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When we click on a video two videos get started playing on flutter web. when I'm coming back from the video_payer screen or after disposing of the controller it still playing in the background but working perfectly on android mobile I have posted all code below for your reference.

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
video_player: 2.4.2
chewie: 1.3.2
```

**TrainingVideos screens**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

const videoUrl = "video_URl";

class TrainingVideos extends StatelessWidget {
  const TrainingVideos({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Two wheeler Insurance",
                    style: FontFamily.mulishBold(15, CustomColors.black),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "View all",
                    style: FontFamily.mulishBold(15, CustomColors.black)
                        .copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 180,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 5,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return const VideoCard();
                    }),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Car Insurance",
                    style: FontFamily.mulishBold(15, CustomColors.black),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "View all",
                    style: FontFamily.mulishBold(15, CustomColors.black)
                        .copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 180,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 5,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return const VideoCard();
                    },),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoCard> createState() => _VideoCardState();
}

class _VideoCardState extends State<VideoCard> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    System.printValue("Initialized :: training video");
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl,)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.pause();
        setState(() {}); //when your thumbnail will show.
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    System.printValue("Dispose :: training video");
    // _controller.dispose();
  }

  String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${duration.inHours!=0?"${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:":""}$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: const Color(0x00000000),
      elevation: 0,
      child: _controller.value.isInitialized
          ? Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                FlatButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _controller.dispose();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const VideoPlayerScreen(videoUrl: videoUrl),),);
                    },
                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      LimitedBox(
                          maxWidth: 180,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                          ),),
                      const Positioned.fill(
                          child: Align(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.play_circle_fill,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 60,
                              ),),),
                    ],),),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Sample Video",
                  style: FontFamily.mulishBold(14, CustomColors.black),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Material(
                  color: const Color(0xffE1E0D1),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                    child: Text(
                      "${_printDuration(_controller.value.duration)} Left",
                      style: FontFamily.mulishBold(12, CustomColors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          : const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 180,
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**VideoPlayerScreen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;

  //VideoPlayerScreen(this.videoUrl);
  const VideoPlayerScreen({Key? key, required this.videoUrl}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late ChewieController chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    System.printValue("Initialized :: video player");
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl,)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });

    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _controller,
      looping: true,
      autoInitialize: true,
      autoPlay: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Business Information",
          style: FontFamily.mulishTitleBold3,
        ),
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.grey[75],
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //_controller.dispose();
            //chewieController.dispose();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => TrainingPromoVideos(),),);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: chewieController,
                ),
              )
            : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    System.printValue("Dispose :: video player");
    // _controller.dispose();
    // chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```